# Default wordpress gallery with like button

Tags: facebook, wordpress, gallery

Wanting to add a like and/or share button on the lightbox overlay with a default wordpress gallery. I know it can be done (more or less) with Nextgen but wanting to avoid having to redo all of the galleries on the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to edit your lightbox template files.  Are you using a plugin for the lightbox or is it included with the theme?  Either way, you will need to locate the file and add your like button there.

Comment: We are using the backstreet theme but it seems the person before me just used the default method for making a wp gallery.

Comment: Can you post a link to your site?

Comment: Looking at the theme page, apparently it comes natively with the option I am looking for but it's not the gallery being used. I have NO idea what the person before me did. http://themeforest.net/item/backstreet-blog-magazine-theme/1680564

Comment: It seems you are using jQuery Colorbox for your light box overlays. This link has instructions for adding buttons to the overlay.  This may be a WordPress plugin or could be coded into the theme.  Basically you need to edit the script calling the jQuery Colorbox. http://dbaines.com/blog/archive/adding-google-1-buttons-to-colorbox/.  That

Comment: Thanks I will look into this. I had no idea.